# Call a future builder again

Tags: flutter, dart

Im stuck in how I can manage to call a future Builder again on a button press to repeat the process indefinitely until it goes OK.

Here is my code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) 
  {
    return FutureBuilder( future: sincroProcess(),
                          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) 
                                    {
                                      if (snapshot.hasData) 
                                      {
                                        Map sincroProcessResponse = snapshot.data;
                                        
                                        if( sincroProcessResponse['allok'] )
                                        {
                                          return ListBody(children: [ OutlinedButton
                                                                      ( 
                                                                        child: Text("Continue"),
                                                                        onPressed: goInit(),
                                                                      ),  
                                                                      Text( sincroProcessResponse['msg'] ) 
                                                                    ]);
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                          return ListBody(children: [ OutlinedButton
                                                                      ( 
                                                                        child: Text("Try again"),
                                                                        onPressed: sincroProcess(), //need this to re-run
                                                                      ),  
                                                                      Text( sincroProcessResponse['msg'] ) 
                                                                    ]);
                                        }
                                      }
                                      else
                                      {
                                        return ListBody(children: [ CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.grey), 
                                                                    Text("We are preparing everything for your first usage =)...") ]);
                                      }
                                    });
  }
}
```

I don't know if I am being clear enough, the behavior of the page should be:
show circular progress while running the sincroProcess, if the response its ok, show a button to go to another page, if not, show a button to re-run the sincroprocess with the circular progress indicator.
I cant imagine how to re-use my code!

Comment: Don't use a future. Use a stream.

Comment: agreed, use `Stream` and `StreamBuilder`

Comment: Been studying the concept all night yesterday, I will post a working answer when I find a way to convert my code to a stream (Sincroprocess).

Answer (score 2):

Make your widget a **Statefull** widget and call `setState()` to rebuild the widget

```
...
else {
  return ListBody(children: [
    OutlinedButton(
      child: Text("Try again"),
      onPressed: (){setState((){});}, //need this to re-run // call setState
    ),
    Text(sincroProcessResponse['msg'])
  ]);
}
```